# Hex Url decoder c#

Tags: c#, url-encoding

i have a URL like http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ewikimoveis%2Ecom%2Ebr%2Ffotos%2F1292%2FKO2551%2FDSC01366%2EJPG

I need to get it decode correctly. I believe that is Hexadecimal. Can't find any C# code that would do that.

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# URLDecode turns %5C into \\\\ instead of \](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608453/c-urldecode-turns-5c-into-instead-of)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [C# URLDecode turns %5C into \\\\ instead of \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608453/c-urldecode-turns-5c-into-instead-of)

```
using System;
using System.Web;

string url = "http%3A2F%2Fwww%2Ewikimoveis%2Ecom%2Ebr%2Ffotos%2F1292%2FKO2551%2FDSC01366%2EJPG"
string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dumbs question... desperate times :)

Comment: Maybe I said it somewhere... but there aren't dumb questions, there are only questions to which the answer is evident. If (because of desperate times, for example) the answer isn't evident to you, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a web application, this is a way:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace urldecoder
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String EncodedString = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ewikimoveis%2Ecom%2Ebr%2Ffotos%2F1292%2FKO2551%2FDSC01366%2EJPG";
            String DecodedString = WebUtility.UrlDecode(EncodedString);
            Console.WriteLine(DecodedString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

See: [system-net-webutility-urldecode(system-string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8#system-net-webutility-urldecode(system-string))